# Passing a parameter along with callback?

Tags: jquery-callback

This is my code:

```
var title = 'test'

function onlineStatus(callback){
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://blabla,
    cache: false,
    success: callback
});

onlineStatus(function(test) {
    // doing stuff with `test`
    $('#forTest').attr('title', title);
});
```

The problem is that the `onlineStatus` call doesn't see `title`, which is correct, because it is out of scope. Is there a way to pass it into the function, so that the `title` is seen?

Comment: I think the issue is that the test argument is scoped locally to the anonymous callback function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function statusCheck (test) {
    console.log(test);
}

function onlineStatus (callback) {
    callback (arguments[1]);
}

onlineStatus (statusCheck, "test");
```